# Project file modified by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I am having the same issue as "csprojfile is forcefully modified in error when any project is opened in Visual Studio", except that only one specific web project is modified (out of dozens),

The fix that worked for Shivendra - delete applicationhost.config - did not have any effect.

The modifications are:

- Anonymous authentication: disabled
- Windows authentication: enabled

I have also verified the settings in IIS Manager.